# authenticate_user! devise for ics stream

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, devise, icalendar

I've set up some events where users can subscribe to calendar events via Outlook/Thunderbird/Iphone so on.

I use devise for authentication and in almost all controllers I have set up this devise method:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

The url for the Icalendar feed is:

```
/events/export_events.ics
```

When I remove the **before_filter :authenticate_user!** line basically you don't have to authenticate and then it's possible to subscribe to events.

I got it on the Phone/Thunderbird and Outlook.

When I uncomment this line I get errors on my Iphone which says:

```
Calendar Subscription
Unable to very account information.
```

When I enter my credentials I get rejected.
It seems like I have to add something to devise so users can authenticate via the Url.

The Rails log says:

```
Processing by EventsController#export_events as ICS
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Any idea's how I could manage to authenticate this ?

Not important side notes but for the sake of completeness.
I use the [Icalendar gem](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) to create/transform my database events into valid Icalendar format.

in my events_controller.rb:

There is the export_events action which works like a charm: 
It totally comes up to the authentication but someone might use this snippet for either understanding the problem or for own projects.

```
def export_events
    @events = Event.first(10)
    @calendar = Icalendar::Calendar.new
    @events.each do |e| 
      event = Icalendar::Event.new
      event.dtstart = e.start.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
      event.dtend = e.end.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
      event.summary = e.title
      @calendar.add_event(event)
    end 
    @calendar.publish
    #headers['Content-Type'] = "text/calendar; charset=UTF-8"
    #render :text => @calendar.to_ical
    @stuff = @calendar.to_ical
    respond_to do |w|
      w.ics { render text: @stuff }
      w.html{}
    end
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    get 'export_events'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to authenticate.
I opened up the devise.rb file.
Where I had to uncomment this line:

```
config.http_authenticatable = true
```